# FutureBuilder gets marked as done early, but only on release builds

Tags: flutter

I'm making a widget that lets the user pick an image from the gallery and upload it to Imgur. I'm using a FutureBuilder to show a loading screen while the image is picked and uploaded. On debug builds, this works fine. The FutureBuilder's ConnectionState is "waiting" until the image is uploaded. On release builds, the FutureBuilder goes to "completed" as soon as the user picks an image.

Here is the widget:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

import '../models/ImgurAPI.dart';
import '../components/getImgurApiKey.dart';

class ImgurUploaderWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  ImgurUploaderWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ImgurUploaderWidgetState createState() => _ImgurUploaderWidgetState();
}

class _ImgurUploaderWidgetState extends State<ImgurUploaderWidget> {
  Future imgurUploaderWidgetFuture;

  Future<void> _pickAndUploadImage() async {
    ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
    ImgurAPI imgurApi = ImgurAPI(getImgurApiKey());

    PickedFile pickedFile =
        await imagePicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    await imgurApi.uploadImage(await pickedFile.readAsBytes());
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    imgurUploaderWidgetFuture = _pickAndUploadImage();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
      future: imgurUploaderWidgetFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print(snapshot.connectionState);
        return Text(snapshot.connectionState.toString());
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not just uploading faster in release mode?

Comment: @Christopher Moore yes, I'm sure. The function was meant to copy the link to the clipboard. I removed it for some more testing but the issue persisted then too.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but there is no such `ConnectionState` called `completed`?

Comment: Also, maybe add a try/catch around your async function to make sure no errors escape.. since you don't check for erros in your FutureBuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgot to set `android.permission.INTERNET` in `AndroidManifest.xml`, causing the upload function to just "skip" because it couldn't connect to the internet.

To do this, I added the permission to `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="me.unicornsonlsd.imgurup">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
...
```